# Can I set SVN to always use the --use-merge-history option?

Tags: shell, svn, alias

Whenever I do an `svn log` or `svn blame` I want it to always use the `--use-merge-history` (or `-g`) flag, so that I can follow the history across branches.

I would prefer not to use a shell alias like `lsvn` or `svn_log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an alias by adding these lines in your ~/.bashrc:

```
f_svn ()
{
        svn $1 -g
}
alias svn=f_svn
```

So whenever you call `svn something` it will do `svn something -g`.

Then, in case you want to call the original `svn` command, you just have to call `\svn`.

Comment: that I know ;) sorry I should written that... I want `svn log` to do a svn log -g, I don't want svn_log or some other alias

Comment: And that's what I am doing :) With my code you would call it with `svn log`. I use `f_svn` to make a function but then I call it with `svn`.

Comment: ah now I see. sorry again ;) I will try that. . you are basically making svn an alias for f_svn and f_svn calls svn?

Comment: Exactly! You explain it way better than I do :)